# How to remove duplicates from an object array using spread operator

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I have below object array with id as unique key":

```js
var test = [
  {id: 1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
  {id: 2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode:""},
  {id: 1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
  {id: 3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: ""}
]
```

From this I want to retrieve unique objects using spread operator, I have tried using below code:

```
const uniKeys = [...(new Set(test.map(({ id }) => id)))];
```

I am able to retrieve id's only, how can I retrieve the unique objects using spread operator. Also, any new ES6 features implementation would be helpful.

Comment: This thread: https://gist.github.com/telekosmos/3b62a31a5c43f40849bb has a bunch of ways to get unique values from an array, including for an array of objects (i.e. filtering array of objects on unique values of a certain key).

Comment: Maybe helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69815213/11302100

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could `map` back to array of objects using `find` method, this will return first object with that id.

```js
var test = [{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},{id:2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode:""},{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},{id:3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: ""}]
var uniq = [...new Set(test.map(({id}) => id))].map(e => test.find(({id}) => id == e)); 
console.log(uniq)
```

You could also use `filter` method instead.

```js
var test = [{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},{id:2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode:""},{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},{id:3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: ""}]

var uniq = test.filter(function({id}) {
  return !this[id] && (this[id] = id)
}, {})
 
console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: when i tried first solution it says "Type 'Set<any>' is not an array type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators."

Comment: @tracer Try `Array.from` instead of `[...]`

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter by unkown `id`.

```js
var test = [{ id: 1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: "" }, { id: 2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode: "" }, { id: 1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: "" }, { id: 3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: "" }],
    unique = test.filter((s => ({ id }) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))(new Set));
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a Map by id and then extract values. `[...new Map(test.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()]`

```js
var test = [{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
{id:2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode:""},
{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
{id:3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: ""}]

console.log([
  ...new Map(test.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()
])
```

Comment: when i tried this it is throwing "Argument of type 'any[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[{}, {}]>'" error

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = [{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
{id:2, PlaceRef: "*00022", Component: "BAXI10R", SubLocCode: "KIT", BarCode:""},
{id:1, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "BATH", SubLocCode: "BAT", BarCode: ""},
{id:3, PlaceRef: "*00011", Component: "ANR190", SubLocCode: "B1", BarCode: ""}];


var uniqArray = Array.from(new Map(test.map(e=>[e.id, e])).values());
console.log(uniqArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash utility library. you can achieve this.
let result = _.uniqBy(test, 'id');