# l want to check if value in array of object dublicated then show one of them on

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, if-statement

```
  let all_map: [
    {
      "name": "sy map",
      "civilization": "sham",
      "continent": "Asia",
      "country": "damascuse",
      "price": 0.0
    },
    {
      "name": "sy map subscribe",
      "civilization": "sham",
      "continent": "Asia",
      "country": "damascuse",
      "price": 0.0
    }
  ]
```

How can I create an `if` statment to check if the country property has the same value as `("country": "damascuse")` in the object to show only one of them?

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly. From what I understood, what you want is, if the value from the key `country` is a duplicate. You want to show only one of them?

Comment: @ChrisG I think that's correct. OP, what one do you want to keep if they are duplicates?

Comment: yes i mean that + this api change by user so i dont know the index of objectes that have the duplicates values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: also [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate objects (based on multiple keys) from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542882/removing-duplicate-objects-based-on-multiple-keys-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained your desired result well, but if I'm understanding correctly, you want to filter out duplicate countries from this array.  My thought is to use `Array.reduce()` to iterate through and create a new array:

```
const reducedMap = all_map.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (accumulator.findIndex(x => x.country === current.country) === -1) {
    accumulator.push(current);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

You didn't specify if you need to keep a *specific one* if there are duplicates.  If that's the case, and, for example, you always want to keep the country that has "subscribe" in the name, then, when a duplicate country is reached in the reducer's iteration, you could add a regex conditional and splice the new object into the array in place of the old one, like so:

```
const reducedMap = all_map.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  const countryIndex = accumulator.findIndex(x => x.country === current.country);
  if (countryIndex === -1) {
    accumulator.push(current);
  } else {
    if (!/subscribe/.test(accumulator[countryIndex].name)) {
      accumulator.splice(countryIndex, 1, current);
    }
  }
  return accumulator
}, []);
```

Comment: yes of course and thank you again (If possible I can take your number or any way to communication ?)

Comment: Missed this when you commented.  I won't post my number on here but if you have any questions about this solution feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let all_map = [{
    "name": "sy map",
    "civilization": "sham",
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "damascuse",
    "price": 0.0
  },
  {
    "name": "sy map subscribe",
    "civilization": "sham",
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "damascuse",
    "price": 0.0
  }
]

if (all_map[0].country === all_map[1].country) {
  console.log(all_map[0])
}
```

Comment: in fact this is api has more other maps  and the user has ability to add to it so i cant know the index of objects that has the same values

Comment: i will thankful if you know how i do this if i dont know the index